# Can I "unstack" RAW+L or RAW+JPEG in Apple Photos?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I often shoot photos in a format that includes a JPEG alongside RAW.

In Apple Photos (on macOS) these are "stacked" together by default. Is there a way to "unstack" them (as was once possible in Aperture, for example)?

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/370985/19829