# Within Photos, delete the RAW file from a "RAW+JPEG" linked pair?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app, camera

I shoot using the RAW+JPEG capture option on my non-iPhone camera.

When I import these images via Photos for Mac, the RAW+JPEG files are added to my iCloud Photos Library as a linked pair. They are given an overlay of two stacked icons, with "J" on the top.

The tooltip of the little square "J" says:

> RAW+JPEG: Jpeg is Original

[image: RAW+JPEG images in Photos on Mac]

I want to continue shooting and importing using this workflow:

1. Shoot in RAW+JPEG
2. Import and backup to iCloud Photo Library as RAW+JPEG
3. *At a later date*, decide to delete the RAW file

Eventually, I'll sort through my photos. I might notice that some of my RAW files are unneeded and want to keep only the JPEG version. I will do this on a case-by-case basis for each image.

At that point, how can I delete the RAW file from the RAW+JPEG linked pair?

I would prefer to do this entirely within Photos. I do not want to "re-import" the images.

Is there any way to discard an iCloud Photos Library RAW file and keep only the JPEG?